# utl_file.fremove erros out when Oracle Grants are present for user (Linux)

Tags: linux, database, oracle, delete-file

I have created oracle directory (SIMPLEDIR) and it points to a physical location on the disk. Oracle version is 12C.

The user has 'CREATE ANY DIRECTORY' and 'DROP ANY DIRECTORY' grants as confirmed by using query

```
            SELECT 'DIR' gtype, PRIVILEGE
            FROM sys.dba_sys_privs
            WHERE grantee = 'MY_TEST_USER1';
```

Can also confirm that the use has rights to create and read files.

```
            SELECT * 
            FROM all_tab_privs 
            WHERE table_name = 'SIMPLEDIR';
```

Now I use the following block to create a file on disk

```
            declare 
                fHandle  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
            begin
                fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('SIMPLEDIR', 'my_test_1.txt', 'w');

                UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fHandle, 'This is the first line');
                UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fHandle, 'This is the second line');
                UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fHandle, 'This is the third line');

                UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fHandle);
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE || '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
                RAISE;
            end;
```

This works fine and can confirm the file is now on the disk and I can also read the file using a simillar script as above.
However when I try to delete the file using the below script I get an error.

```
            declare 
                fHandle  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
            begin  
                utl_file.fremove('SIMPLEDIR', 'my_test_1.txt');
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE || '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
                RAISE;
            end;
```

The error message is as follows

```
            Error report:
            ORA-29291: file remove operation failed
            ORA-06512: at line 8
            29291. 00000 -  "file remove operation failed"
            *Cause:    A file deletion attempt was refused by the operating system.
            *Action:   Verify that the file exists and delete privileges granted on
                the directory and the file.
```

It is not a file lock issue since if I create a file and copy to the same location manually, still it fails to delete. How can I get more detail on the exact cause of the error.

To me it looks like a OS level issue since the error message has 'A file deletion attempt was refused by the operating system.'.

This works fine in internal systems where DB is hosted in windows server, but fails on customer where the DB is hosted on Linux.

Comment: What are the permissions on the file on disk? Who's the owner? What logon is being used by the DB? Group memberships? Etc?

Comment: The files has read, write, execute grants for owner and group (-rwxrwxr-x). We can create dummy files in the said directory, however cannot delete those generated dummy files. Strange...

Comment: Parent directories did not have write privileges. Thanks